# Classic ASP: How to reload the page, preserve url parameters and add a new one?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm working with a "Multi-Language Page" - And I want to change the language and preserve all url parameters in the page - because the page is using this values.

ex:

page.com/demo.asp?name=John&color=Blue

If the user click on language and change the language I need to:

1- Send a new parameter -

Here I guess - the best way to do this is send another parameter like this:

page.com/demo.asp?name=John&color=Blue&lang=ES

right?

Then I create a link on "ES" option with this URL.

```
> create_url =
> Request.ServerVariables("URL")&"?"&Request.ServerVariables("Query_String")
> new_url = REPLACE(create_url, "&lang=", "&newlang=")
```

The REPLACE works to avoid multiples "&lang" on the url if the user change the language many times.

and HTML:

```
<a href="<%=new_url%>&lang=ES">ES</a>
<a href="<%=new_url%>&lang=EN">EN</a>
<a href="<%=new_url%>&lang=PT">PT</a>
<a href="<%=new_url%>&lang=FR">FR</a>
```

When I click the link - page is reload - all parameters still valids - and I can add the "LANG" now.

but...

MY ISSUE:

IF I HAVE NO ONE PARAMETERS IN THE URL - and "&LANG" is the FIRST

I got a BUG...

because I will pass this:

page.com/demo.asp?&LANG=ES

and the correct way is

page.com/demo.asp?LANG=ES

without the "&"

any idea?

tks a lot!!!
Daniel

Comment: It still works with the extra `&` so why bother? ... and do note, with the extra `&` it is not invalid, and I can guarantee no visitors is gonna complain,if they at all see it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `replace` with that kind of RegEx :

https://regex101.com/r/MRmZ00/3

`(.*[?&]lang=)[A-Z]{2}(.*)`

Output : `'$1' + newlang + '$2'`

Working if it's your only parameter or your first one `?lang=ES` or anywhere else in the url `&lang=ES`.

Answer (score 0):

> URI.js is a javascript library for working with URLs. It offers a "jQuery-style" API (Fluent Interface, Method Chaining) to read and write all regular components and a number of convenience methods like .directory() and .authority().

[Here is link](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

Here is example :

```
URI(location.href).addQuery("lang", languageName);
```